# How to Add MX.Core Package ActionScript in SWF/FLA file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action, builder

I'm trying to add ActionScript 3 in FLA file using Flash Professional, but I am getting error that Packages cannot be nested. I am completely new but It's necessary for me to add that code in FLA/SWF file, I guess it will work with Flash builder but again I have no idea to edit FLA or add ActionScript using Flash Builder.
Please Help!

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I want to make simple advertisement banner with the actionscript code I've given by my friend but that actionscript is showing an error while adding in the FLA file. ( Flash CS6)

Comment: That is not the answer of my question. What have you done/tried? What code?